# How to solve this problem with useEffect? Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

**I want to useEffect use it here but it does not fit. How do you think I should use it?**

**

```
const Sidebar = (props) => {
      var [state, setState] = useState({
        collapsed: false,
        theme: "dark",
        current: "1",});
      const changeTheme = (value) => {
        setState({
          theme: value ? "dark" : "light",
        });
      };
      const onCollapse = (collapsed) => {
        console.log(collapsed);
        setState({ collapsed });
      };
```

---

```
  const { collapsed } = state;

  const { Sider } = Layout;`enter code here`

  const { SubMenu } = Menu;`enter code here`

  return (
    <div>
      <Sider
        collapsible
        collapsed={collapsed}
        onCollapse={onCollapse()}
        width={256}
        theme={state.theme}>
        <div className="Logo">
          <img src="/image/User_icon.png" style={{ width: 80, height: 90 }} />
        </div>
        <div className="switch">
          <Switch checked={state.theme === "dark"} onChange={changeTheme()} checkedChildren="Dark" unCheckedChildren="Light" />
        </div>
</div>
 )};
 export default Navber;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVvFj.png)

Please help, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is with `onCollapse` prop in your `<Sider />` component. Technically you are calling `onCollapse` function on each renders, that's why you are getting that error message.

The main difference is either you **pass a callback** into a prop, or calling that and **pass its result**.

Instead either you can use as:

```
onCollapse={onCollapse}
```

Or the other way:

```
onCollapse={() => onCollapse()}
```

Usually I prefer the first option.

Also I realized you have exactly the same issue on `onChange` prop in your `<Switch />` component. Try `onChange={changeTheme}` instead of `onChange={changeTheme()}`.

See one small example below for further explanation:

```js
const onCollapse = () => {
  return 'return value'
}

// see the result
console.log('result', onCollapse())

// see the callback function
console.log('callback', onCollapse)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but now I tried what you said, but now I have another problem and Coollapse it does not work